# Wix: Redirect a User-Agent To A Specific Page?

Tags: user-agent, googlebot, velo

What would be the best way to redirect a user-agent such as 'google-bot' or 'bing-bot' to a specific page on my wix-site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [Wix Routers](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-router) and [redirect()](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-router/redirect) - only thing is that Wix Routers are only available on Router and Dynamic Pages, not normal site pages.

In the [Wix Router Request](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-router/wixrouterrequest/useragent) object you get the user agent